# Why left column "push" content of right column?

Tags: html, css

I implemented the one-fixed, one-fluid column layout and I don't know why left column (regards to height) "push" my part of content down.

```css
.profile-left-column {
    width: 105px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0 15px;
    float: left;
    height: 500px;
    background: #ddd;
}
.profile-right-column {
    margin-left: 105px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 1265px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.clearfix:after {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
}
.gc:after {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
}
.gcpad {
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}
.g1_4 {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-height: 20px;
    background: #66f;
}
.gpad {
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-left-column"></div>

<div class="profile-right-column">
    <div>      
        <div class="gc gcpad">
            <div class="g1_4 gpad"></div>
            <div class="g1_4 gpad"></div>
            <div class="g1_4 gpad"></div>
            <div class="g1_4 gpad"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="gc gcpad">
            <div class="g1_4 gpad"></div>
            <div class="g1_4 gpad"></div>
            <div class="g1_4 gpad"></div>
            <div class="g1_4 gpad"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v3gma4d2/1/ (this two blue bars should be directly under themselves)

Could someone explain me why something like this happens? And how to solve issues?

Comment: is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/v3gma4d2/2/) what you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set an element to float, the elements after the floating element will flow around it. Imagine that we normally float an image and the text (enough multiple lines) next to the image goes even under the image.

You have the similar case like that, you **only** set the left column to float, the right column is actually flowing around it, and as soon as the *clearfix* is added, it all breaks immediately. See the simple demo follows.

```css
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.right {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.inner {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.inner:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">1</div>
<div class="right">
    2
    <div class="inner">3</div>
    4
</div>
```

**To fix the problem**. You can either set right column to `overflow:auto`, or `hidden`, to prevent it from wrapping underneath the left column.

```css
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.right {
    border: 1px solid green;
    overflow: auto; /*ADDED*/
}
.inner {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.inner:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">1</div>
<div class="right">
    2
    <div class="inner">3</div>
    4
</div>
```

**Or**, to set the right column to float too (you will also need to give it a fixed or percentage `width`, The [**`calc()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) CSS function can be very useful in this case.).

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.right {
    float: left; /*ADDED*/
    width: calc(100% - 100px); /*ADDED*/
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.inner {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.inner:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">1</div>
<div class="right">
    2
    <div class="inner">3</div>
    4
</div>
```